# Exclude Encrypted Jar from jacoco analysis

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

How to exclude cncrypted jar from jacoco analysis as it is giving ClassNotFound Exception ?
I have tried to remove the jar using excludes inside configuration in the jacoco-maven-plugin. But that didn't work. Someone please help.

Thank You in Advance.
Here is the plugin configuration i am using.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/companyname/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have also tried com.companyname.*.

Comment: try giving the actual path relative to your workspace. i.e. ` <exclude>target/main/classes/com/companyname/*</exclude>`

Comment: @ArunSangal have tried it already. not working.

Comment: Can you paste the error mesg. If you can show which class is actually showing an error for Class Not Found. Try excluding all `**/*.class` or `target/main/classes/com/companyname/**/*.class` and see if that gives you any hint. Also mention what's the folder which store your class files

Comment: @ArunSangal Thank you for your help. I got the problem now. Actually ClassGuard doesn't work with java agents that's why i was getting NullPointerException. This problem was not from the jacoco agent side.

Comment: Do share your answer with complete(high-level) details so that it can help someone like you someday. Thanks.

Comment: @ArunSangal Thank you for your concern about everyone. I just got to know that ClassGuard doesn't work with java agents and jacoco uses java agent to do instrumentation. So it's not possible to use jacoco for code coverage while using encrypted libraries for the project. As workaround I am trying to find other ways to get code coverage for my project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following configuration for jacoco executions worked.

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/myJar.jar/**</exclude>
</excludes>
```